# CSS How to add new pseudo content

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

```
.newclass {
    content: "\00A9";
}
```

In the above code, a copyright icon shows up. I have a question and a requirement.

Question - Where is this icon come from? any image from my pc, internet or some other way.

Requirement - If I have to introduce a new code, and associate a new icon for that code, how to do it?

Comment: Those are unicode characters. Check [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin) for a full list.

Comment: It is difficult to imagine a good reason to add a character like “©” via generated content, as opposite to having it in content. You might be solving the wrong problem.

Comment: It’s a character, not an icon. It is unclear what you mean by introducing a new code and associating a new ison.

Answer (score 1):

It's an unicode escape sequence, 
here you can find some examples:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Answer (score 0):

these works with pseudo elements and are unicode characters.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EFAtk

there a list here : http://unicode-table.com/en/

HTML test

```
 &copy;
<p> &#64;
<a href="http://unicode-table.com/en/">http://unicode-table.com/en/</a></p>
```

CSS test

```
:before {
color:red;
}
body:before {
    content: "\00A9";
}
p:before {
  content:'\0040';
}
```